# How to Align a Button With Navigation Menu Class?

Tags: css, mobile, navigation, squarespace

Site is on Squarespace if it matters. This is for mobile only. I replaced the standard hamburger menu with the word "Menu" and a black border with the following code:

```
button.header-burger-btn.burger {
   visibility: hidden; 
}
button.header-burger-btn.burger:after {
   visibility: visible;
   content: "Menu";
   font-family: poppins;
   border: solid;
   padding-top:2px;
   padding-bottom:2px;
   padding-left:2px;
   padding-right:2px;
   color: #000;
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

The original hamburger menu was aligned horizontally with the logo in class "header-display".

When I submitted the custom CSS above the Menu button is now lower on the screen. I want to align it on the same horizontal line as "header-display", so it's directly across from our logo in the nav bar.

Comment: Can you provide images and the related HTML code. Or can you provide a jsfiddle.net/ or a code snippet for a minimal reproducible code?

Comment: Here's an image of our homepage on mobile. You can see that the "Menu" button is not on the same horizontal plane as the logo: https://imgur.com/a/wlwXIgV.

Comment: I believe this is the related HTML code:                                                               
<div class="header-display" data-content-field="site-title">
        <!-- Social -->
        
          
        

        <!-- Burger -->
        <div class="header-burger
        ">
          <button class="header-burger-btn burger">
            <div class="burger-box">
              <div class="burger-inner"></div>
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>

Comment: Hi there. For questions such as this involving Squarespace, it's usually best to include a link to the site/page in question (if the site is in trial mode, set Site Visibility to "Password Protected" and include the view-only password too). A less ideal, but still viable, alternative is to state which template you are using.

Comment: Got it. Sorry about that. Here's the site, it's public: https://www.weacceptcryptocurrency.com/